# In Psalm 3:3, what does David mean by saying to YHVH, "You are my glory"?

Tags: psalms

In Psalm 3:3, what does David mean by saying to YHVH, "You are my glory" and how might it relate to the taunt in the previous verse?

> ESV Psa 3:3  But you, O LORD, are a shield about me, **my glory**, and the
>   lifter of my head.

The previous verse:

> ESV Psa 3:2  Many are saying about me, "Even with God on his side, he
>   won't be victorious." Selah

Comment: I think it's verse 4.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot  What is verse 4?

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot It's verse 4 in the Hebrew but verse 3 in English. Wounded, it's always helpful if you cite the translation you're using.

Comment: @Susan  I've edited the post to add the version (ESV).

Comment: From Webster's, the noun [glory](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glory) is *something that brings praise or fame to someone or something : something that is a source of great pride*. This seems to be a theme in David's life.

Comment: @tniles09, I think you are onto something, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

God is his glory the lifter of his head, i.e. he seeks nothing from men. He understands God controls all things, therefore looks to God not man for help.

God is his "glory" means he's thankful to God, and for his thanks he is glorified by God by having such a close relationship with him. This caused him to increase his love for the most high, which means Gods love mercy and abundance was all the more present in his life.

May the peace and mercy of our most high creator be with us.

Answer (score 1):

> But you, O LORD, are always my shield from danger; you give me victory and restore my courage.
>   -- Psalm 3:3 `GNT`

With regard to the expression “the One lifting up my head”, one reference work says:

> When God lifts up . . . one’s ‘head’, He fills one with hope and confidence.

Forced from Israel’s throne, David has reason to be despondent. However, ‘the lifting up of his head’ will result in renewed courage, confidence, and complete trust in God.